# What is the meaning and origin of the suffix “-son”?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, surnames

A friend recently asked me the meaning of the name *Madison*. Although I wasn’t sure of the meaning of *Madison*, it prompted a discussion about the suffix *‑son*, seen in a lot of names: Jefferson, Henderson, Johnson, Harrison, etc.

I suspect it comes from English, as these names seem to be English in origin, but other than that I could find no information pertaining to the suffix.

**tl;dr:** What is the origin and definition of the suffix *‑son*?

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU. Please try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=suffix+son) for an answer before posting here. If you don't find a satisfactory answer, mention what you found in your question and why it was not enough.

Comment: Surely this is General Reference. My surname is *Harrison* - as it happens, my father's forename is *Harry*, but that's just coincidence. Somewhere back in history was the original Harry whose child adopted the disamguating name *Harry's **son** = Harrison*. So far as *Madison* is concerned, it's [*a variant of Mathieson meaning son of Matthew*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madison_(name)). Again, GR.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Tell me you are actually Harry Harrison, Harry's son :). Your father is not by any chance the recently deceased and much lamented author, [Harry Harrison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Harrison_%28writer%29)? My condolences and profound respect if so.

Comment: @terdon: Sadly, no can do. He does actually have a *grandson* called Harry (a nephew, not mine), but I think it's a real hassle having to disambiguate them as *"Big Harry"* and *"Little Harry"*. Besides, the youngster is now physically bigger, and getting tired of the handle (16 years ago, nobody expect the now-94-year-old to be still around long enough for a problem to arise! :). I don't really understand why [three generations of Loudon Wainwrights](http://www.lw3.com/) would have wanted to perpetuate this kind of "ancestor-worship".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means son. Many languages use an equivalent ending: Mendelssohn, Jespersen. Icelandic still has individualized surnames and you can find Jónsson along with a sister, Jónsdóttir.

Madison  - Either means "son of Maud" or "son of Matthew," depending on your source. I was unable to find a source I would claim reliable enough to settle it, and perhaps none exists. It is very likely that there are multiple sources.

Comment: I don't think that *Maud* is likely to be right. It's very unusual for the *female* parent's name to be used in this way.

Comment: Unusual, yes; but not unheard of. Icelandic footballer [Heiðar Helguson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heiðar_Helguson), for example, is named after his mother (Helga), rather than his father. @Rubric: Just to be really pernickety, you’d more accurately find _Jónsson_ and _Jónsdóttir_ in Icelandic. :-)

Comment: (That’s not to say that Madison is from Maud. It might be in some cases, but most Madisons are likely from Matthew’s son, Mathi(e)son, as mentioned in @FumbleFingers’ comment to the question itself above)

Comment: Apparently, "George" [was rarely used in England until the German-born George I came to the British throne in the 18th century,](http://www.behindthename.com/name/george), which presumably explains why there aren't many Georgesons today. There are plenty of people with surnames based on most [boy's names popular in medieval times](http://www.infernaldreams.com/names/Europe/Medieval/England.htm), but I don't know of anyone at all with a surname based on the popular ***girl's*** names in that link.

Comment: There is the surname "Alison."

Comment: "Marriott" is derived from "Mary" and became a popular surname after crusaders returned to England. According to [this website](http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Madison), Maud or Mahalt were popular feminine names in England due to Matilda, the wife of William the Conqueror, and that's the primary source of Madison surnames. (Although I'm sure a portion are corruption of Matthi(e)son, too.)