# Why using -son instead of -daughter?

Tags: american-english, names

I am learning English and my teacher taught me a lesson where there was a person named Bill Robertson and his sister's name was Dyna Robertson. So why was her name Dyna Robertson when she is a *daughter*? Why not Dyna Robertdaughter?

Comment: You should have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Patronymic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic) naming.

Comment: "Why not Dyna Robertdaughter?" - they do that in Iceland.

Comment: @KillingTime thank you for your answer. I am new to english and it is difficult for me to understand that article. But I will see it later after I became good.

Comment: she’d be Robertsdaughter in Sweden, too.

Comment: JackSON, AnderSON, ThomSON, PeterSON, ClarkSON, these are all very common last names in Anglophone speaking countries. I have never heard of anyone for example of being called JackDAUGHTER. Why is this so? Because we are still a patriarchal society, and it is the son who carries the name of the family  onto the next generation. Traditionally the daughter loses her family name and adopts that of her spouse.

Comment: related: **1**. [keeping maiden name after marriage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47027/) **2**. [Can “Mrs” be used before the name of a spouse who keeps her maiden surname?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394884/) **3**. [What is the meaning and origin of the suffix “-son”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124963/) **4**. [Are all English surnames-made-first-names masculine?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45978/)

Comment: and... **5**. [What do Americans call a 'double-barrelled surname'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151402/)

Comment: Surnames in England aren't patronymics. The son of John Robertson would be called Simon Robertson, not Simon Johnson. Wikipedia has a vast amount of information on virtually every country and culture's naming traditions: see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surname

Comment: Tradition!!!!!!

Comment: In case this need reiterating, last names ending in "son" are remnants of the distant past. Today a child of James Abbot, would not be called *Jameson* or *Abbotson* even though these last names do exist, a child usually inherits their father's last name unaltered. Some children inherit both parents' last names which is known as **double-barrelled name**

Answer (score 2):

In English, family names are usually passed down from a father to his children without any changes. So if a man is named Paul Johnson, then all of his children, regardless of gender, will also have the last name Johnson (not Paulson or Paulsdaughter). If one of those children is named David Johnson, then all of David's children will probably have the last name Johnson (not Davidson or Davidsdaughter).

At some time in history, centuries ago, the name "Paul Johnson" really would have meant "Paul, John's son." However, names no longer work that way in English-speaking countries.